# Vote Early, Vote Often!

Tags: discussion, voting, votes

I would like to echo a post that [Scott Morrison made on Meta.Tex.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12/vote-early-and-often):

> I'm a moderator from MathOverflow, and this "question" is actually unsolicited advice, based on our experience from the initial launch of MathOverflow.
>
> > We should encourage everyone to vote positively as often as possible!
>
> Every Stack Exchange site will eventually end up with a different "base level" of voting --- that is, the expected number of upvotes for a question of a given level of excellence. (This effect occurs because people see a good question, but already with a certain number of votes, and think "oh, I would have upvoted this, but it already has enough".)
>
> It's easy for us to affect this "base level" by encouraging high levels of upvoting now. We're setting the standards, and this really will have an effect.
>
> (On MathOverflow, we were very active about this early on, specifically encouraging all the initial round of users to vote early and often. You can compare statistics, and see that the average vote total for a MathOverflow question is much higher than on any of the other SE 1.0 sites.)
>
> In case it's not obvious: the rationale for wanting this base level to be high is that it provides better positive feedback to good contributors."

Vote early and vote often to rid us of those unnecessary/poor quality posts and make our site one with high quality posts! Use your moderation privileges while you can! Close, upvote, downvote, flag, etc.

## Did I also mention to vote early and vote often?

Comment: though the same meta.TeX post has an answer showing where [both principles &quot;vote early&quot; and &quot;vote often&quot; can be problematic](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12/vote-early-and-often/2021#2021). One would have to guard against activity just for the sake of appear active in site stats, rather than adding high-quality answers.

Answer (score 8):

I'd like to resurrect this post to hit this point home again, especially when traffic to the site slows down.  We should continue to vote on quality posts and encourage users to continue posting great questions and answers.  We've attracted a lot of views from reddit and hacker news recently (I've been trying to share as many relevant questions as possible on social media), and we need to make sure users who come for one question and post an answer stick around to provide more answers, especially if they are high quality.